# rpy2 importr failing with xts and quantmod

Tags: r, conflict, xts, rpy2, quantmod

I'm new to rpy2 and am having trouble using importr to import the R packages 'xts' and 'quantmod'

Code is:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
xts = importr('xts')
quantmod = importr('quantmod')
```

Errors are:

```
LibraryError: Conflict when converting R symbol in the package "xts" to a Python symbol (.subset.xts -> _subset_xts while there is already _subset_xts)

LibraryError: Conflict when converting R symbol in the package "quantmod" to a Python symbol (skeleton.TA -> skeleton_TA while there is already skeleton_TA)
```

I don't get this problem using importr for many other packages, e.g. 'stats', 'graphics', 'zoo', 'ggplot2'

Versions:

- python version 2.7.3
- R version 2.15.2
- rpy2 version '2.3.0beta1'

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Rpy2's `importr()` is trying to convert any "." in R object names to "_" for usage with Python.

However, whenever there are two R object names with either "." or "_" (both characters are valid for names in R) rpy2 is reporting an error. Here the R package "xts" is defining the two objects `.subset_xts` and `.subset.xts`. The workaround is specify manually how to convert names:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import import
xts = importr("xts", robject_translations = {".subset.xts": "_subset_xts2", 
                                             "to.period": "to_period2"})
```

More is available in the rpy2 documentation about [importing R packages](http://rpy.sourceforge.net/rpy2/doc-dev/html/robjects_rpackages.html?highlight=importr#importing-r-packages).

Comment: Amazingly, this also happens (to me at least) when importing `stats`. I had to retranslate `format.perc` to something other than the default, since `format_perc` also exists.