# rpy2 fails to import 'rgl' R package

Tags: python, r, rpy2

To <s>load the `rgl` package</s> check if the `rgl` package is installed in `R` from within `python`, I'm combining the recipes given in these two questions:

[rpy2: check if package is installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15761756/rpy2-check-if-package-is-installed)

[rpy2 importr failing with xts and quantmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649562/rpy2-importr-failing-with-xts-and-quantmod?lq=1)

Here's the MWE I put together:

```
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeError
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')

def importr_tryhard(packname, contriburl):
    try:
        if packname == 'rlg':
            rgl = importr("rgl", robject_translations = {".rgl.abclines": "_rgl_abclines2"})
        else:
            rpack = importr(packname)
            print 'success'
    except RRuntimeError:
        print 'no pack'
        rpack = 'none'
    return rpack

packname = 'rgl'
contriburl = 'http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/'
importr_tryhard(packname, contriburl)
```

The above code keeps failing with the error:

```
rpy2.robjects.packages.LibraryError: Conflict when converting R symbol in the package "rgl" to a Python symbol (rgl.abclines -> rgl_abclines while there is already rgl_abclines)
```

According to the answer given in the second question linked at the beginning of this question, the line:

```
rgl = importr("rgl", robject_translations = {".rgl.abclines": "_rgl_abclines2"})
```

should take care of this error, but apparently it is not.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

**Edit**

A comment below by Spacedman made me realize there was a typo in the original question above (`if packname == 'rlg'` should be `if packname == 'rgl'`). Correcting this typo, I was able to make the code work, as follows:

```
from rpy2.rinterface import RRuntimeError
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')

def importr_tryhard(packname, contriburl):
    try:
        if packname == 'rgl':
            rpack = importr("rgl", robject_translations = {"rgl.abclines": "rgl_abclines2",
                "rgl.attrib": "rgl_attrib2", "rgl.attrib.count": "rgl_attrib_count2",
                "rgl.bbox": "rgl_bbox2", "rgl.bg": "rgl_bg2", "rgl.clear": "rgl_clear2",
                "rgl.dev.list": "rgl_dev_list2", "rgl.getcolorcount": "rgl_getcolorcount2",
                "rgl.getmaterial": "rgl_getmaterial2", "rgl.ids": "rgl_ids2",
                "rgl.init": "rgl_init2", "rgl.light": "rgl_light2", "rgl.material": "rgl_material2",
                "rgl.pixels": "rgl_pixels2", "rgl.planes": "rgl_planes2", "rgl.pop": "rgl_pop2",
                "rgl.postscript": "rgl_postscript2", "rgl.primitive": "rgl_primitive2",
                "rgl.quit": "rgl_quit2", "rgl.selectstate": "rgl_selectstate2",
                "rgl.setMouseCallbacks": "rgl_setMouseCallbacks2", "rgl.setselectstate": "rgl_setselectstate2",
                "rgl.snapshot": "rgl_snapshot2", "rgl.spheres": "rgl_spheres2", "rgl.sprites": "rgl_sprites2",
                "rgl.surface": "rgl_surface2", "rgl.texts": "rgl_texts2", "rgl.user2window": "rgl_user2window2",
                "rgl.viewpoint": "rgl_viewpoint2", "rgl.window2user": "rgl_window2user2"})
        else:
            rpack = importr(packname)
        print 'success'
    except RRuntimeError:
        print 'no pack'
        rpack = 'none'
    return rpack

packname = 'rgl'
contriburl = 'http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/'
importr_tryhard(packname, contriburl)
```

So it actually works, but it's terribly cumbersome and ugly. I suggest using the code I posted in [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28698178/1391441) which is a far better way to check for installed packages.

Thanks Spacedman!

Comment: is `if packname == 'rlg'` a typo and should be `rgl`?

Comment: @Spacedman you are correct! Your comment made me realize the code actually works and I edited the question to show this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that. The rgl package needs an OpenGL device, but running in the confines of rpy2 is more like running headless.

Comment: Does that mean that I simply won't be able to check if the `rgl` package is available in `R` from within a `python` script?

Comment: You need a test that does require loading as you can't do that wit rgl from rpy2. Look eg at `installed.packages()`.

Comment: That function seems to be what I need, thank you! Now I just need to figure out how to correctly read its output: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28697549/read-r-function-output-as-columns

Comment: I don't think that this is correct. The R embedded through rpy2 can be as interactive as R running in its R console.

Comment: Loading of rgl regularly fails for me when I test Rcpp against reverse depends in a headless envrionment.  If you're interactive, the rgl via rpy2 may well work --- but that is not where we generally run (automated, cron-drive) deployment tests.

Answer (score 1):

You are almost certainly not fixing all symbols creating an error. In the case of `rgl`, there are quite a few so may consider building the dictionary using an alternative name translation rule.

For example, changing `'.' -> '_'` to `'.' -> '__'`:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
base = importr('base')
base.library('rgl')
env = base.asNamespace('rgl')
d = dict()
for k in env:
    if '.' in k:
        new_k = k.replace('.',  '__')
        d[k] = new_k
rgl = importr("rgl", robject_translations=d)
```

Comment: Wonderful. This is how I would've done it if I had known how to do it :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking Dirk's answer as accepted because he was right. Nonetheless, I'm posting my own answer here to show how I solved this issue.

Here's the code:

```
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
utils = importr('utils')

def importr_tryhard():
    contriburl = 'http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/'   
    try:
        pack_lst = utils.installed_packages()
        rpack = list(pack_lst.rx(True, 1))
    except RRuntimeError:
        rpack = []
    return rpack

rpack = importr_tryhard()
print rpack
```

This will return (stored in `rpack`) a list of all the available packages in `R`.

Comment: Good to post the answer, but it is the answer to a _modified_ question :)  You didn't initially ask about "how do I find what is installed" ...

Comment: You are correct Dirk, I initially said I wanted to _load_ the package, which was not the case (see: http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/28687322/1) I've added a cross-out line to the question reflecting this edit.