# rpy2 importr failing with 'TTR' package

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I've used rpy2 to import R packages before but am having trouble using importr to import the R packages '**TTR**'
code is:

```
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri  # for dataframes
pandas2ri.activate()
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
ttr = importr('TTR')
```

I'm getting Error as:

```
rpy2.robjects.packages.LibraryError: The symbol .env in the package "TTR" is conflicting with a Python object attribute
```

I've seen similar question [rpy2 importr failing with xts and quantmod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13649562/rpy2-importr-failing-with-xts-and-quantmod) but for package 'TTR', I don't know what parameter to give in `importr` parameter `robject_translations = ''`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What the error message is telling is that the symbol `.env` in the R package, when translated to a syntactically valid name in Python (here the translation will be `_env`), is conflicting with an attribute of the object `ttr` you are creating when calling `importr`. You can see that attribute for objects of class `Package` here: https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/_modules/rpy2/robjects/packages.html#Package

How to use the parameter `robject_translations`is documented:
https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/robjects_rpackages.html#importing-r-packages

Comment: sorry for late response, and thanks for your answer. can you please tell me what should I use as pameter in  ' Importr ' for    robject_translations = {".env": "__env2"}

Comment: Should work. If it doesn't, file a bug on the rpy2 page on bitbucket.